# creating a web app based on what people text/sms to a phone

Tags: mobile, sms-gateway

Hi
Can someone recommend the best way (app service or how I can setup my own) to create a phone number on the web which I can text messages via my mobile phone and I program the responses? For example creating a Alice AI chat bot through my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up playing around with https://api.hashblue.com/doc/Home

Answer (score 0):

Try www.tm4b.com for the sms gateway part